# PEM error when Im trying to deploy an app to Google Play through Azure DevOps

Tags: android, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

When im trying to deploy my app bundle using the Google Play - Release Bundle task in Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

[image: Azure DevOps Hosted Agent output]

```
##[section]Starting: Release D:\a\r1\a/_CI Workout Pipeline to Google Play Store
==============================================================================
Task         : Google Play - Release Bundle
Description  : Release an app bundle to the Google Play Store
Version      : 3.192.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : ms-resource:loc.helpMarkDown
==============================================================================
Found main bundle to upload: D:/a/r1/a/_CI Workout Pipeline (version code %s)
##[error]Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
##[section]Finishing: Release D:\a\r1\a/_CI Workout Pipeline to Google Play Store
```

I have setup an service account in the Google Play Console, but I do not see anywhere to look for a PEM starting line.

[image: View of the Service account in Google Play Console]

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to deploy an android app in Azure DevOps. Private key in a Google Play service connection was empty in my case.
Ensure you have created [a private key](https://buddy.works/docs/faq-hidden/google-play-private-key-and-permissions) and added the key to a service connection in Azure DevOps.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31271118)

Answer (score 0):

Certificate/secret is downloaded when you 'invite' a user to your play console.

To do this (if you haven't already)

- go to Play Console
- go to API Access under Setup (if you're in a App, go to 'all apps' first)
- Clink on 'create new service account'
- This shows a dialog with instructions on how to create service accounts in Google Cloud Console (yes, excellent UX)
- Once you created the service account in Google Cloud, go to that user and in to 'KEYS' and Add a new key
- select JSON as the format
- this downloads a JSON file with the key and some other information
- Store this securely and take note of the private key in it.
- Navigate back to play console, click done and add permissions to the new account
- In Devop connection, enter the private key string, WITHOUT escaping JSON

  - DO NOT escape \n in the key.

Example input to the devops task will look like below

```
----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvA...rnA==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Note that you should only exclude the quotation marks and keep the JSON encoding, including the last `\n` after `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`.